# IS having Multiple indexes on the same table is a problem as i am doing only Read calls

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, database-performance

Queries are running longer and longer. Trying to attain some performance by creating Indexes.

We have some automated Select queries hitting Database to read the Data.  My database is serving only READ queries. SO I Created whole bunch of index on the table to help queries. My understanding on the Indexes is:
As we are not doing any insert/update/delete, having multiple indexes doesn't harm anything. My question is : Is it a problem of having multiple indexes on the tables as my Database(MS SQL server) is serving only Read Calls. Some of the indexes that I created may not even required.

My expectation is to make sure all of my select queries are using proper index and not facing any Performance Problem because of using wrong index or missing index.

Comment: Many index <> useful indexes. I strongly suggest you sampling little data with the profiler then feeding them to the tuning advisor and create only the needed index. SQL SERVER may not always get the best index.

Comment: Indexes *improve* read performance, they don't degrade it. It's insert/update that takes longer because there are more indexes to update.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question though withouth knowing what the query is, the table schema, the indexes and the execution plan. Most likely the queries require different indexes. Or the queries may be badly written. Or it could be that the storage is too slow

Comment: What do the execution plans for the slow queries look like? What are the expensive operations? Are there any table or index scans? That means the indexes weren't all tha useful and the server had to scan an entire table or index to find matches

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that indexes take up space on your hard disk so whenever you back up the database you may have a slightly longer backup and larger backup.

To see if SQL Server thinks you are missing indexes you can try running the script from here https://basitaalishan.com/2013/03/13/find-missing-indexes-using-sql-servers-index-related-dmvs/ which uses built in DMVs to determine what indexes are 'missing.'

You may also look at individual queries to see if they could be improved by opening the query in SQL Server Management Studio and pressing Ctrl_L which will show you the query plan.

All this is appropriate on database(s) that are not being updated. If it is indexes can slow down inserts and updates.